# How can I grow list dynamically for my problem

Tags: apex

Hi I have following code

```
List<String> listS = new List<String>();
List<String> listS1 = new List<String>();
listS.add('abc');

Integer count = 0;
if(listS.size() == 1) {
   do {
     listS1.add(count, listS.get(0));
     count++;
  }while(count == 4);
}
system.debug(listS1.size());
for(String s : listS1)
 system.debug(s);
```

I want listS1 to grow until 4 size with content copied from listS. If I give an index then its throwing index out of bound exception and if don't give index then its adding only one value.

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to do in this code or why. Should your while condition be `while(count <= 4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your do-while loop condition is not correct. The loop ends if the condition is false, so since count isn't four after the first iteration, it terminates after just one cycle. Instead, it could be `count < 4`, or ideally `listS1.size() < 4`.

As for which add function to use, you can't specify an index to insert to when the list is empty, so use the single parameter version.